# Search and replace file content using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I want to search and replace specific value in a file, here is the content of the file

```
filename: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I want to replace `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` with `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/centos`

I tried the following

```
sudo sed -i "s#DocumentRoot /var/www/html#DocumentRoot /var/www/html/centos#g" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

This is not working, can someone point me to the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you are trying to replace is:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

It contains double-quotes. The `sed` command does not include the double-quotes. Try:

```
sudo sed -i 's#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/centos"#g' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i figured it out, i was missing double quotes, following command worked

```
sudo sed -i 's#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/centos"#g' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```